# How do you convert a JCE algorithm name into an AlgorithmIdentifier object?

Tags: bouncycastle, jce, oid

I'm using BouncyCastle 1.54.

I have a JCE algorithm string - like "ECDSAwithSHA256" (for example).

I need an org.bouncycastle.asn1.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier object.

Alternatively, I could create an AlgorithmIdentifier object from an OID, but that begs the question of how to translate an algorithm string into an OID instead.

I could create a giant if/else, but there's got to be a standard way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the algorithm finders of BouncyCastle (see [javadoc](https://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pkixdocs1.5on/index.html?org/bouncycastle/operator/DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder.html))

```
import org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder;
import org.bouncycastle.operator.DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder;

AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(signatureAlgorithm);
AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
```

The `AlgorithmIdentifier` OID's obtained for `SHA256withECDSA` (not `ECDSAwithSHA256`, see [bouncycastle specifications](https://bouncycastle.org/specifications.html)) will be

```
1.2.840.10045.4.3.2
2.16.840.1.101.3.4.2.1
```