# BouncyCastle - set custom alias to algorithm

Tags: java, digital-signature, bouncycastle

I'm trying to verify signature digest using Bouncy Castle.
The digest algorithm is SHA1.

Unfortunatelly the digest algorithm is set in the signature as SHA1WITHRSA (which is NOT a digest algorithm) instead of just SHA1.

There is nothing I can do about it.

Now I need to tell Bouncy Castle to use SHA1 when it encounters SHA1WITHRSA as a digest algorithm.

Is it possible to add an alias that would lead to SHA1 digest algorithm?

I tried this:

```
BouncyCastleProvider bcp = new BouncyCastleProvider();
bcp.put("Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.SHA1WITHRSA", "SHA-1");
bcp.put("Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5", "SHA-1");
Security.addProvider(bcp);

MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1WITHRSA", "BC"); // throws an exception
MessageDigest.getInstance("1.2.840.113549.1.1.5", "BC"); // throws an exception
```

But with no success..
I'm getting java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException.

The full stack is here:

```
no such algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA for provider BC
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA for provider BC
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:698)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:227)
    at com.company.Main.testAddDigest(Main.java:82)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

and the same for 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

```
no such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 for provider BC
java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: no such algorithm: 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 for provider BC
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(GetInstance.java:87)
    at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:206)
    at java.security.Security.getImpl(Security.java:698)
    at java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:227)
    at com.company.Main.testAddDigest(Main.java:95)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

There is no such digest algorithm SHA1WITHRSA, which makes it correct to throw the exceptions.
But I thought that by adding the "put" lines, the aliases will be added and then the SHA1WITHRSA would be recognized as SHA1 digest algorithm.

**UPDATE:** It is working when I use the specific instance of Provider:

```
MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1WITHRSA", bcp);
```

I'm not sure how to add the alias generally to all instances of BC not just the created **bcp** variable (BouncyCastleProvider). If it is even possible.

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Yes, I've added the exception to the question.

Comment: Check the Javadoc of BouncyCastleProvider.put and see if it's suitable for your needs

Comment: put sets the property name and its value. When trying different values for both, I was checking the SHA1.java, Mappings class, configure method (https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/master/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/digest/SHA1.java#L94)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I've figured it out.

I'm not sure anyone would meet scenario like this, but..

The problem was that I was playing with the **DSS** (https://github.com/esig/dss, framework for handling digital signatures).
It uses **Bouncy Castle**.
I was testing it on a specific PDF which has its digest algorithm attribute set to `SHA1withRSA` (which is incorrect, there should be just `SHA1`).
But the task was to process it as it has set the correct value - `SHA1`.

So I needed to tell the bouncy castle to use `SHA1` whenever it encounters `SHA1withRSA` set as a digest algorithm.

I didn't want to modify the framework code too much (ideally not at all) and I certainly didn't want to modify any of the Bouncy Castle code.

The following code solved it:

```
BouncyCastleProvider bcp = (BouncyCastleProvider)Security.getProvider("BC");
bcp.addAlgorithm("Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.SHA1WITHRSA", "SHA-1");
bcp.addAlgorithm("Alg.Alias.MessageDigest.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5", "SHA-1");
```

It gets the Bouncy Castle provider and adds two aliases routing to SHA-1 digest algorithm whenever the `SHA1WITHRSA` or `1.2.840.113549.1.1.5` is set as digest algorithm (which they are NOT!).

One can argue that such PDF should not be verified, but that's different thing..

Answer (score 0):

To verify a signature just use this code

```
Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
sig.initVerify(publicKey);
sig.update(data)
boolean verifies = sig.verify(sigToVerify);
```

You're confusing signature algorithm with digest algorithm. `SHA1withRSA` is a signature algorithm. It means that the digital signature operation performs a hash of data with `SHA1` digest algorithm, and then performs `RSA` encryption

Therefore the `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException` on `MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1WITHRSA", "BC");` is the expected behaviour because `SHA1withRSA` is not a digest algorithm

### EDITED

If you want to know the digest algorithm of the signature algorithm, you can use  BouncyCastle's finders.

```
AlgorithmIdentifier sigAlgId = new DefaultSignatureAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(signatureAlgorithm);
AlgorithmIdentifier digAlgId = new DefaultDigestAlgorithmIdentifierFinder().find(sigAlgId);
String digestAlgOID = digAlgId.getAlgorithm().getId();
MessageDigest.getInstance(digestAlgOID);
```

Comment: Hi @pedrofb, thank you for the answer. I should have added more context. I know that SHA1withRSA is signature algorithm, but in some documents I was validating this value is set also as digest algorithm attribute. Don't ask me why. There is also signing certificate verification in the process and when it comes to verifiing the digest it compares the digest set in signature with the one just calculated. And there is the trouble if it tries to calculate the digest, the digest algorithm name it gets from signature is SHA1withRSA.

Comment: I'm limited to change the code. I'm using 3rd party OSS which uses Bouncy Castle where the signature verification takes part and I would have to change the BC source which I don't think is a good idea for production use.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem. It would help if you include the full code involved. In any case, if you want to know the digest algorithm of the signature algorithm use  BouncyCastle's finders. See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38475100/6371459

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I've figured it out.